# Validation in zend-form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

While using change password in Zend Form,I want to check old password and new password.Both should not be same.Is there any option in Zend Form to check the both.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do it when you process the form in your controller or model code. It should just be comparing the new hash to the old hash to make sure they don't match.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Library under My and use the following:

```
class My_Validate_PasswordConfirmation extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    const NOT_MATCH = 'notMatch';
 
    protected $_messageTemplates = array(
        self::NOT_MATCH => 'Password confirmation does not match'
    );
 
    public function isValid($value, $context = null)
    {
        $value = (string) $value;
        $this->_setValue($value);
 
        if (is_array($context)) {
            if (isset($context['password_confirm'])
                && ($value == $context['password_confirm']))
            {
                return true;
            }
        } elseif (is_string($context) && ($value == $context)) {
            return true;
        }
 
        $this->_error(self::NOT_MATCH);
        return false;
    }
}
```

[More Information at the : Zend Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html)
Scroll down to or find :

> Note: Validation Context

On the source page. Code is given right below it and so is the explanation.

Hope it helps! :)